# "Identifier Expected" error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, unityscript, identifier

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour {

var totalhealth = 100;

    function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
        if(other.tag == "angelic_sword_02"){
            totalhealth -= 50;
        }
    }

    function Update(){
        if(totalhealth <= 0){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an "Identifier Expected" in the script where it says in the line

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider) {
```

Any help please?

Comment: What language are you using? This is *not* C#.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: It's partially C#.  Unity supports multiple extension languages.  It looks like code from two examples, using two languages, mixed together.

Comment: @EricJ. I see, some bastard child of C# then. Is `var` allowed to define a field?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Nope.

Comment: It's C# compiled with Mono.  Not sure which version of C# is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax for a C# method.  Unity supports multiple  languages for user code.  Perhaps you copied an example from a different language?

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider){
    if(other.tag == "angelic_sword_02"){
        totalhealth -= 50;
    }
}
```

Should be closer to

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if(other.tag == "angelic_sword_02"){
        totalhealth -= 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me out, and I guess I'm not that good at scripting yet, and I'm still studying both C# and Javascript, so I tend to mix both of them up. But now I'm getting a new error for "var". I forgot what you put there instead. I know it's not "function" because that's Javascript.... right? You put "void' instead...right?

Comment: We all start somewhere.  It does look a lot like JavaScript.  Just change `var` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. And I have no more compiler errors anymore.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour {

public float totalhealth = 100;

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if(other.tag == "angelic_sword_02"){
        totalhealth -= 50;
    }
}

void Update(){
    if(totalhealth <= 0){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

@EricJ thank you for helping me out. :)